# How do i remove an image from a report in Access. When i am trying to remove the image it is giving me an OLE server error?

Tags: database, ms-access, ole

I am new to using MS Access. I have an application in Access which uses VBA code. It has some reports which uses a logo. Now, i want to change this logo. So when i tried to delete it, it gave me an error "The OLE server isn't registered".

Can anyone help. I am sure there are a lot of people who can help me with this.

Thanks in advance
Sachin

Comment: What version of Access are you working with?

Comment: Can't you simply open the report in design view and delete the control which contains the image?  Or is that what you're already trying to do when you get the error?

Comment: You could have a missing reference.

Comment: I'd bet dollars to doughnuts that your installs of MS Access is broken. Most of the references to that error I've found indicate something wrong with one DLL or another. Have you tried it on a different workstation?

Comment: @HansUp : That is what i am already trying to do. :( Sadly it doesnt work for me. Moreover, the application has forms as well which contain the logo. Those i can delete easily ... but not the logos on the reports.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me using access 2013. I right clicked on the object and found the 'change to' dialogue. I changed the object to an image and Access allowed me to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I created plots in MS Access and I could not remove them. The error was:

"The OLE server isn't registered. To register the OLE server, reinstall it."

Everything worked well in the past, but after a major upgrade to MS Access 2016 these plots did not work. These plots were obsolete and removing them was the best choice. However, MS Access did not let me delete them.

The solution, as explained in the text, was to "right click" the plot, select "Change To", and select "Image". Afterwards, the plot can be deleted.
Great solution.